# Will the resistance of the certain valued resistor decrease or increase at cryogenic temperature?

Tags: resistance, temperature

I tried to measure resistance of 332k Ω while dipping in liquid Nitrogen (cryogenic temperature) I got the resistance value near about 458k Ω, doesn't it contradicting "*Resistance should increase and decrease with increase and decrease respectively with surrounding temperature*"?

Comment: It's just a trend that resistance increases with temperature. Otherwise things like NTCs would not exist. I don't know what regular resistor material decreases resistance as temperature increases though. You need to provide us with the resistor information.

Comment: There are PTC, NTC materials and even semiconductors.

Comment: I had used general purpose Carbon Composition Resistor (CCR).

Comment: @learner you might have to correct for a lot of effects there. I don't trust a resistance measurement when there's high temperature differences involved – Seebeck effect vs low measurement currents.